# Validator pattern part of multiple validator not working

Tags: angular

I have two validator for my field in angular (this is

```
[FormFields.field1]: ['', [Validators.maxLength(4), Validators.pattern('[0-9]')]],
```

this is part of:

```
private initForm(formBuilder: FormBuilder): void {
    this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
      [FormFields.field1]: ['', [Validators.maxLength(4), Validators.pattern('[0-9]')]]
    });

  }
```

for some reason even if I add an entry like 111 in the input field the field is evaluated as invalid.

Isn't this the correct way to define the validator that accepts only digits:

```
Validators.pattern('[0-9]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the validation as below and please check:

```
Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(4),Validators.pattern('[0-9]*$')])
```